# Show Discontinuity in Paraview

Tags: paraview

I am trying to visualize data containing points of discontinuity.

Target function is right part of the following
[formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpBMh.png).

The correct way to plot the data is [this gnuplot plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6xLo.png)

Paraview visualize it [incorrectly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PwqX.png), it draws some extra lines in place discontinuity points.

I used python script to generate .csv with my function values

```py
import numpy as np
import csv

def beta(x):
    return 2 * x 

def g(x,c):
    return np.sqrt(-2*(c-1) * c * np.cos(x) + 2*(c - 1)*c + 1)

def phi_k(x,c):
    return 1 - 1 / (x * c) * np.arctan(c * np.sin(x) / (1 - c + np.cos(x)))

cS = [1, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25]

xS = np.arange(-np.pi/2, np.pi/2, 0.01, dtype='float64')

headers = [f"C={c}" for c in cS]
headers.insert(0,'x')

modulus = []
error = []

for x in xS:
    modulus_row = {'x' : x}
    error_row = {'x' : x}
    for c in cS:
        modulus_row[f"C={c}"] = g(beta(x),c)
        error_row[f"C={c}"] = phi_k(beta(x),c)
    modulus.append(modulus_row)
    error.append(error_row)

with open("courant_modulus.csv", 'w') as modulus_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(modulus_file, fieldnames=headers)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(modulus)

with open("courant_error.csv", 'w') as error_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(error_file, fieldnames=headers)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(error)
```

Then I imported courant_error.csv into ParaView and used LineChartView.

How can I visualize my data the same way I performed it in gnuplot?

**Edit** Fixed myself by performing little changes in data generation script

```py
import numpy as np
import csv

def beta(x):
    return 2 * x 

def g(x,c):
    return np.sqrt(-2*(c-1) * c * np.cos(x) + 2*(c - 1)*c + 1)

def phi_k(x,c):
    return 1 - 1 / (x * c) * np.arctan(c * np.sin(x) / (1 - c + np.cos(x)))

cS = [1, 0.75, 0.5, 0.25]

xS = np.arange(-np.pi/2, np.pi/2, 0.0001, dtype='float64')

headers = [f"C={c}" for c in cS]
headers.insert(0,'x')

modulus = []
error = []

def is_nan(x,c):
    return abs(1-c + np.cos(beta(x))) < 0.001

for x in xS:
    modulus_row = {'x' : x}
    error_row = {'x' : x}
    for c in cS:
        modulus_row[f"C={c}"] = g(beta(x),c)
        error_row[f"C={c}"] = np.nan if is_nan(x,c) else phi_k(beta(x),c)

    modulus.append(modulus_row)
    error.append(error_row)

with open("courant_modulus.csv", 'w') as modulus_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(modulus_file, fieldnames=headers)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(modulus)

with open("courant_error.csv", 'w') as error_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(error_file, fieldnames=headers)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(error)
```

You can set NaN value in some points nearby your discontinuity point.

Comment: Add a datapoint with a NaN value